# Number of dataframe partition value is showing different in spark UI as compared to partition value calculated using dataframe.rdd.getNumPartition

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

Image-1)
[image: Image 1 of spark UI(Job section)]

Image-2)
[image: Partition calculation using getNumpartion]

- Job Id 0 denotes = getting number of partitions for orders dataframe
- Job Id 2 denotes = getting number of partitions for customer dataframe

Which seems out to be 20 and 1 for orders_DF and customer_DF respectively when calculated using->

- `orders_df.rdd.getNumPartitions` it is showing 20 partitions
- `customer_df.rdd.getNumPartitions` it is  showing 1 partition

But in the screenshot attached for the spark UI , the partitions are 1 and 1 for orders_DF and customer_DF respectively.

what is the reason for this conflict/difference in the number of partitions?

Broadcast Join is disable in this case. We have used normal  join in this example.

Comment: can anyone explain this?